# Javascript reference in for-of loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

With regular for loop I can do something like that:

```
for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    delete objects[i];
}
```

It's not possible with regular for-of loop

```
for (let o of objects) {
    delete o;
}
```

That will generate such error

> SyntaxError: Deleting local variable in strict mode.

And this is expected, `o` is a copy. So, is there a way to initialize `o` as a reference? For example, this is how it's done in C++11:

```
for (auto &o : objects) {
    // o is a reference to an object from objects
}
```

Comment: Use a for-in loop with checks? Or just stick to your for loop...

Comment: Are you sure you want `delete`?, and not `splice`?  seen as your using an array.

Comment: Side note: you should not "initialize" objects this way if performance is among your concern.  `delete` is the worst performance killer in JS engine. You should refactor your code so that you can replace your object with a new one, or maybe just set the values as `undefined`.

Comment: That's interesting, I was about to ask what are the best practices in javascript when it comes to deleting objects. What's the best way to mark object as no longer needed so garbage collector could remove it? Set it to undefined as @DenysSéguret suggested? (And all objects it contains that were created using new operator)

Comment: When you stop referring to a value (most frequently because the current scope isn't used anymore) then it's garbageable. You **don't** manually mark values for deletion in JS (or in any modern memory managed language).

Comment: Yep, but I mean - how to exactly do that. Let's say it's only referenced from an array. It seems that using splice is a better way to remove it from there. But as far as I understood, you also mentioned replacing that object with a new one which is undefined. Would that be a better idea than just to use splice? (performance-wise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with an [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, which provides the array item along with the index of the item to the iterator function.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  delete arr[index];
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

`delete` will never *actually* delete the underlying object - if a property on an object (or array) is a reference to an object, such as with your `objects[i]`, and you delete the property from the object (which is doable with `delete`, eg `delete objects[i]`), then that object (`objects[i]`) will still exist in memory (for now). It'll only be *actually* deleted once *nothing else* can reference it and the garbage collector runs.

For example, with the following code:

```
const obj = { foo: 'foo' };
const arr = [obj];
```

Nothing you could to do `arr` can de-reference the object that `obj` points to. (You could *mutate* it, eg `for (const prop of arr[0]) delete arr[0][prop]`, but you can't remove the object itself from memory.)

If each object in the array is not referenced anywhere else, then the way to de-reference all of them so that they'll be GC'd is with your original code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    delete objects[i];
}
```

or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support `delete` applied to objects - it's a syntax error as posted. The delete operator in JavaScript *only ever applies to removing a named property from an object.* The type and value of the property is of no consequence.

Hence

```
let a= [{}];
delete a[0];
```

removes the property named "0" from `a`. The anonymous object that was stored in the array has no further references anywhere in code, and will be collected by the GC.

But

```
 let a = [{}];
 for (let o of a) {
    delete o;
 }
```

is a [syntax error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) generated by a bad `delete` expression - there's no property name provided to be deleted.

> And this is expected, o is a copy.

**may** still be alluding to C++.  Object data values in JavaScript are references to an object's data structure. It could be a memory pointer but that would be entirely dependent on the JavaScript engine.

The language provides no means of accessing the internal reference/pointer value or performing any address operations on it. A copied object value will refer to the same data structure as the value it was copied from.

Manipulations of an object's properties can be performed on any reference or copied reference to it. Also of note, JavaScript objects do not support destructors. An object's memory resources may be reclaimed by the GC when no accessible code can still access it.